# Pagination breaks the page markup

Tags: templates, pagination

Hello!

I have an index page template with 3 columns. Each column has pagination buttons in the bottom. You can see the screenshot below (I've highlighted the buttons by red rectangle).

[image: An index page template with 3 columns]

But then I go to the next page by clicking pagination button I get the broken markup. See the screenshot below

[image: The broken markup]

The template code:

```
{embed="global/header" page_title="рейтинг пива, статьи и полезная информация о пиве"}
  <div id="left_col">
    <div id="last_news" class="grid_10_index">  
    {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6" dynamic="no" paginate="bottom"}
        <div class="last_news_item">
            <div class="last_news_item_title_wrapper"><div class="last_news_item_title"><a href="{url_title_path='news'}">{title}</a></div></div>        
            <div class="last_news_item_body">

                <div class="last_news_item_date">{if news_date!=""}{news_date format="%j %M %Y г."}{if:else}{entry_date format="%j %M %Y"}{/if}</div>

                <div class="last_news_item_author">автор: {if news_author!=""}{news_author}{if:else}{author}{/if}</div>

                <div class="last_news_item_content">
                    {if news_announce!=""}
                        {news_announce}
                    {if:else}
                        {exp:trunchtml chars="300" ending="<a href="{url_title_path='news'}">...</a>"}
                            {news_body}
                        {/exp:trunchtml}
                    {/if}
                </div>
                <div class="last_news_item_comments">{if comment_total}<a href="{url_title_path='news'}#news_item_comments">Комментариев: {comment_total}</a>{/if}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
{paginate}
    {pagination_links}
        <ul id="pages">
    {page}
        {if current_page}
            <li class="pages_item active"></li>
        {if:else}
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="{pagination_url}"></a></li>            
        {/if}

    {/page}
        </ul>
    {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
</div> 

<!-- <div id="last_actions_wrapper" class="grid_9">
</div> -->

<div id="center_col" class="grid_10_index">
    {!-- <div id="last_events"><a href="#"><span>Последние события на сайте</span></a></div> --}
    <div id="last_comments_wrapper" class="round_5">
        <div id="last_comments">
            <div class="last_comments_title">
                Последние комментарии
            </div>
            <div class="last_comments_item odd">
                <div class="last_comments_item_author">VIPERRR666</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_date">22.04.2013</div> 
                <div class="last_comments_item_content">
                    Не плохое пиво, но пока оно холодное, пил я его прошлым летом - как теплеть начинает, так всё... помойка.... уже не помню, но там чё то с градусами был косяк - в одном месте на бутылке...
                </div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_topic"><a href="#">Amber Weiss Wheat Beer</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_comments_item even">
                <div class="last_comments_item_author">Сергей</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_date">19.05.2013</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_content">
                    В Москве пока было обнаружено только в Ашане
                </div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_topic"><a href="#">Юзберг Weissbier</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_comments_item odd">
                <div class="last_comments_item_author">Алексей</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_date">20.05.2013</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_content">
                    В центре - практически в каждой палатке продаётся....
                </div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_topic"><a href="#">Юзберг Weissbier</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_comments_item even">
                <div class="last_comments_item_author">Гость</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_date">25.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_content">
                    Вот интересно, как сравнивая Венское Хамовники и Венское Цвай Мастер можно умудриться оценить второе выше? Хамовники - очень вкусное пиво, с небольшой горчинкой и мощным солодовым вкусом, а Цвай Мастер... не о чем...
                </div>
                <div class="last_comments_item_topic"><a href="#">Хамовники венское</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="pages">
            <li class="pages_item active"></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>


    <div id="last_posts_wrapper">
        <div id="last_posts">
            <div class="last_posts_title">
                Новые темы на форуме
            </div>
            <div class="last_posts_item odd">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">VIPERRR666</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">22.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Где в Москве попить пива?
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Сергей</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">19.05.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Странная информация на бутылке...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item odd">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Виталий</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">17.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Есть ли пиво в России?
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Недовольный</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">14.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Проблемы с сайтом
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item odd">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Водка</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">22.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Пейте водку !!!
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Монах</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">19.05.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                    Предлагаю траппистское пиво своего произв...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="last_posts_item odd">
                <div class="last_posts_item_author">Папа Римский</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_date">17.04.2013</div>
                <div class="last_posts_item_content">
                   Жаль у нас в Ватикане нету такого сайта(((
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ul id="pages">
            <li class="pages_item active"></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="right_col" class="grid_4_index">
    <div id="last_tests_wrapper">
        <div id="last_tests">
            <div class="last_tests_title">
                Последние пробы
            </div>
            <div class="last_tests_item">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="last_tests_item_title">
                        <div class="last_tests_item_img">
                            <img src="/img/beer/asterie.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="last_tests_item_name">ASTERIE</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="last_tests_item_type">Blanche</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_strength">4,9%</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_country"><img src="/img/flags/belgium.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_rating">7</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="last_tests_item">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="last_tests_item_title">
                        <div class="last_tests_item_img">
                            <img src="/img/beer/altmuller.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="last_tests_item_name">ALTMULLER</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_type">Weissbier</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_strength">5,4%</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_country"><img src="/img/flags/german.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_rating">7.5</div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="last_tests_item">
                <a href="">
                    <div class="last_tests_item_title">
                        <div class="last_tests_item_img">
                            <img src="/img/beer/uzberg.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="last_tests_item_name">ЮЗБЕРГ MUNCHENER HELLES</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_type">Pilsner</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_strength">4,8%</div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_country"><img src="/img/flags/russia.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="last_tests_item_rating">6</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="pages">
            <li class="pages_item active"></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="pages_item"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    {embed="global/footer"}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this trouble?

Comment: Can you, please, show us your code?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can see it below.

Answer (score 1):

can't see the code but seems to me you forgot a closing div with the pagination block

Comment: You can see the code above.

Comment: Compare the html that's output to the browser on the first page to the output html on the second page, and look for differences in the structure. Finding a missing div or more will point to where the trouble is in the template code.